# NSHTMLTextDocumentType not showing in attributed text view for paged VC

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to format text within a UITextView using the NSHTMLTextDocumentType.  The UITextView is on a page/VC of a PageViewController.

It all works fine and when I tested in the simulator it worked.
Except... when I switched the the device and started dragging between pages in the PageViewController the text stopped showing.  I realised that when using the simulator on the laptop I click rather than drag to change pages.

So the formatting works/fails in the following situations:

- work: clicking with a quick automatic pagecurl affect between pages
- work: programatically changing pages via a timer
- fail: dragging with a pagecurl affect between pages

Interestingly, when a page fails to render the text from dragging to the next page:

- the code is being called properly.  I debug and see everything being set.  Even the attributed text is showing the right values.
- when I rotate the device so the page is redrawn it puts the text there (so the VC has the info from viewDidLoad which isn't run on orientation change).

My theory is that the rendering of html is too slow so the pagecurl effect get's the VC before it is fully rendered and doesn't show the text.

My code for rendering the textView is in the viewDidLoad and looks like the below.  All three methods use the same functional to generate the VC.

```
//set the html text
var htmlData:String = "<P><H1>test</H1></P>"
htmlData += "<P>Some <B>more</B> text</P>"
htmlData += "<UL><LI>1</LI><LI>2</LI></UL>"

//convert the html to attributed text
let attributedData = htmlData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding)
informationTextView.attributedText = try! NSAttributedString(data: attributedData!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)

//set the font
if let font = UIFont(name: "StoneSerifMedium", size: 12.0) {
    informationTextView.font = font
}

//Force the scrollable area to top left    
informationTextView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, -999), animated: true)
```

Questions:

- How do I make the page curl show the attributed html text?
- Failing that, should I be using another text formating?  I noticed it does seem slow.  The main feature I want is a bulleted list as a section of the text.  This doesn't appear to be in the normal attributed text functionality.

Answer (score 0):

When running on the device (not in simulator) I noticed I was getting a warning about a bogus layer size:

```
2016-01-08 12:43:06.640 ThaiFootMassage[7061:4333540] -[<_UITileLayer: 0x15fea56a0> display]: Ignoring bogus layer size (3163616608641188102144.000000, 2361183241434822606848.000000), contentsScale 2.000000, backing store size (6327233217282376204288.000000, 4722366482869645213696.000000)
```

Also noticed that occasionally the text would appear but be down the page quickly, then disappear.

Commenting out the following line fixed the warning and started showing the text:

```
//Force the scrollable area to top left    
//informationTextView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, -999), animated: true)
```

I assume attributable text (html) allows for blank area above the rendered text so it was scrolling off the bottom.  Plain text would stop at the top.